# cannot refactor module for plugin because of cache

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I created simple plugin for `sublime text 3` (which uses another my simple module `module1`):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/forStack')
import module1

class simple_pluginCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):      
        print("Hello World")
        module1.method1()
```

I run it in `sublime command line` (ctrl+`)

```
view.run_command('simple_plugin')
```

It Outputs:

```
Hello World
Hello module1.method1()
```

Where `module1` is ...

```
def method1():
    print("Hello module1.method1()")
```

Then I refactor  `module1` (change method name and its content):

```
def method2():
    print("Hello module1.method2()")
```

... save module1 with output:

```
Writing file /Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/forStack/module1.py with encoding UTF-8 (atomic)
reloading plugin forStack.module1
```

Then I change plugin text accordingly to call module1.method2():

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/forStack')
import module1

class simple_pluginCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):      
        print("Hello World2")
        module1.method2() #------------------------- change only here
```

Save it with output:

```
Writing file /Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/forStack/simple_plugin.py with encoding UTF-8 (atomic)
reloading plugin forStack.simple_plugin
```

And then try to call my `simple_plugin` again and got output with error:

```
Hello World2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 549, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/forStack/simple_plugin.py", line 10, in run
    module1.method2()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'method2'
```

It seems that it "caches" somewhere `module1` and dont take changes. So how to disable or refresh that "cache"?

**UPDATE:**

Now I can refresh that "cache" in 2 ways:

1. Closing sublime and reopening it.
2. Renaming `module1` to `module2` for example.

Both methods are too time wasting.

Comment: It worked fine for me. I followed the same steps as you, though I did replace your syspath modification and import statement with `import User.module1 as module1`. Of course, I would change User to be whatever package your module is in. It appears to be `forStack`. That being said, there is still some caching going on as I can still call `module1.method1()` after I've renamed it to `method2()`.

Comment: Thank you for testing. So you got exact the same issues as I described with refactoring `module1` with some mysterious cache?

Comment: No it reloaded fine for me. `method2` worked as expected.